# How to display image from controller to view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have images in a folder and not in the database, i want to display the particular image (my image path is in the form of string) from controller to view,  with other data in asp.net 6 mvc

I tried Viewbag, tempdata and all the other things. I am unable to find a way in .net 6, all the solutions are in previous version which is not working in .net 6

Things i have tried
view
// 

controller

```
{
  var data = _context.tbl_scotequine.Where(e => e.Ueln == ueln)
            .Select(e => new EquineCard
            {
                name = e.Name1,
                colour = e.Colour,
                sex = e.Gender,
                microchip = e.Microchip1
               //Path = $"C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/scotequine original source code/storage/data/cards/uploads/cropped{ueln}.jpg"
              }); 
                var res = data.ToList()[0];
                
                ViewBag.Path = Url.Content($"C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/scotequine original source code/storage/data/cards/uploads/cropped{ueln}.jpg"); 
                return View(res);
}
```

I have also tried this

```
{
                var Path = $"C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/scotequine original source code/storage/data/cards/uploads/cropped{ueln}.jpg";

              
                var data = _context.tbl_scotequine.Where(e => e.Ueln == ueln)
                .Select(e => new EquineCard
                {
                    name = e.Name1,
                    colour = e.Colour,
                    sex = e.Gender,
                    microchip = e.Microchip1
                    image = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Path)
            }); 
                var res = data.ToList()[0];
```

Comment: post the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action, you're already retrieving the image path and setting it in the `ViewBag`. However, you should use `Url.Content` to generate a URL relative to the web application root:

```
public IActionResult YourAction(string ueln){
    var data = _context.tbl_scotequine.Where(e => e.Ueln == ueln)
        .Select(e => new EquineCard
        {
            name = e.Name1,
            colour = e.Colour,
            sex = e.Gender,
            microchip = e.Microchip1
        });

    var res = data.FirstOrDefault(); // Use FirstOrDefault to avoid exceptions

    if (res != null)
    {
        string imagePath = $"~/data/cards/uploads/cropped{ueln}.jpg"; // Assuming it's in your wwwroot directory
        ViewBag.Path = Url.Content(imagePath);
        return View(res);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case when no data is found
        return NotFound(); // or any other appropriate action
    }
}
```

In your view (`YourView.cshtml`), you can display the image using the `img` tag with the URL from `ViewBag.Path`:

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Path" alt="Equine Image" />
```

Make sure the image path provided in `imagePath` is relative to the `wwwroot` directory, which is where static files like images should be stored in an ASP.NET Core application. The `Url.Content` method generates a URL that is relative to the web application root.

Ensure that your application is configured to serve static files from the `wwwroot` folder in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
    // ... other middleware setup

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // Enable serving static files from wwwroot
}
```